# How to append to window.onload?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function, `foo`, that I would like to add to `window.onload` however my problem is that there is already another function, `bar`, set to window.onload. How can I get both functions attached. I have no access to change the logic of how `bar` is added to `window.onload` therefore I can’t use the paradigm `addEvent(…)` . Would something like the following work in all cases?

```
<script>
$(window).load(foo(){
//my code here
});
</script>

//lots of html
//potentially this happens before or after my above script

<script>
window.onload = bar();
otherFunction(){
//other function code here
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a non-issue since you're using jQuery. You can call `$(window).load(...)` multiple times and it won't stomp out previously-bound event handlers.

This function takes an anonymous function as a parameter, which is executed once the load event is fired.  e.g.

```
$(window).load(function() {alert('the window has loaded');});
```

JQuery Documentation of the `.load()` handler: https://api.jquery.com/load-event.

For reference, the equivalent "vanilla" JS would be to use [`window.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

---

**Update**

Instead of the `.load` event, use `.on('load,'`:

```
$(window).on('load', function() { alert('This is better'); });
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37915907/361842 for more.

Comment: Thanks that makes me feel better and solves my problem. Ill accept your answer in five minutes

Answer (score 3):

A function can't be appended to, however you could use `addEventListener` and then register several functions for the `load` event:

```
window.addEventListener("load",a);
window.addEventListener("load",b);
function a(){
  alert("one");
}
function b(){
  alert("two");
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to mess with `addEventListener` given that the OP is using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/hmtl; charset=utf-8'/>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      window.addEventListener("load",foo);
      window.addEventListener("load",bar);
      function foo(){
        alert("this");
      }
      function bar(){
        alert("that");
      }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why did you minus me? And a better solution is to call something like 'initPage()' function on load and then call whatever functions you want from that