# jquery 3.0 url.indexOf error

Tags: jquery, jquery-3

I am getting following error from jQuery once it has been updated to `v3.0.0`.

`jquery.js:9612 Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function`

Any Idea why?

Comment: check this, may be it resolves your problem [Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function on indexOf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471229/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-on-indexof)

Comment: it's the new version of jQuery firing the error. Old version is fine.

Comment: im running into this right now too :0

Comment: Please declare the answer. I think it's obvious we have one

Answer (score 641, accepted):

**Update** all your code that calls `load` function like,

```
$(window).load(function() { ... });
```

**To**

```
$(window).on('load', function() { ... });
```

---

> jquery.js:9612 Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function

This error message comes from `jQuery.fn.load` function.

I've come across the same issue on my application. After some digging, I found this statement in [jQuery blog](https://blog.jquery.com/2015/07/13/jquery-3-0-and-jquery-compat-3-0-alpha-versions-released/),

> .load, .unload, and .error, deprecated since jQuery 1.8, **are no more**.
>   Use .on() to register listeners.

I simply just change how my jQuery objects call the `load` function like above. And everything works as expected.

Comment: It's crazy they don't have a big deprecated warning on this page in their docs, http://api.jquery.com/load/.

Comment: I found this the be the exact problem I was having when bootstrapping zurbs foundation into aurelia

Comment: kind of ironic that the only place I actually was still doing this was in error handling code that then broke itself :-/

Comment: I used it in `document.ready` function and it is working like a charm.

Comment: Not working dear, getting same error. Code is as <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).ekkoLightbox();
  });
});
</script>

Comment: i have also added code in document.ready but still not working. any suggestion?

Answer (score 37):

Better approach may be a polyfill like this

```
jQuery.fn.load = function(callback){ $(window).on("load", callback) };
```

With this you can leave the legacy code untouched. 
If you use webpack be sure to use script-loader.

Comment: Thanks so much. I still got an error, James suggested you use .trigger this worked. jQuery.fn.load = function (callback) {$(window).trigger("load", callback); };

Comment: Amazing solution when it's caused by third party JS. Another plus is that it doesn't require a downgrade, which will cause vulnerability (in any jquery version below 3!).

Comment: This answer is king

Comment: my 2cents: `jQuery.fn.load = function(callback){ jQuery(window).on("load", callback) };`, use `jQuery` insted of `$` if not working (like in many WordPress...)

Comment: I also had to add a return statement so it supports chaining.

`jQuery.fn.load = function(callback){ jQuery(window).on("load", callback); return this; };`

Answer (score 16):

Jquery 3.0 has some breaking changes that remove certain methods due to conflicts. Your error is most likely due to one of these changes such as the removal of the .load() event.

Read more in the [jQuery Core 3.0 Upgrade Guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed)

To fix this you either need to rewrite the code to be compatible with Jquery 3.0  or else you can use the [JQuery Migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) which restores the deprecated and/or removed APIs and behaviours.

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same error after updating to the latest version of JQuery. Therefore I updated the jquery file I was working on, as stated in a previous answer, so it said `.on("load")` instead of `.load()`.

This fix isn't very stable and sometimes it didn't work for me. Therefore to fix this issue you should **update** your code from:

```
    .load();
```

**to**

```
    .trigger("load");
```

I got this fix from the following source: https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/pull/1024

Comment: thank you, kind sir, for stating the solution in your answer and not sending me to dig the docs myself.

Answer (score 0):

@choz answer is the correct way. If you have many usages and want to make sure it works everywhere without changes you can add these small migration-snippet:

```
/* Migration jQuery from 1.8 to 3.x */
jQuery.fn.load = function (callback) {
    var el = $(this);

    el.on('load', callback);

    return el;
};
```

In this case you got no erros on other nodes e.g. on `$image` like in @Korsmakolnikov answer!

```
const $image = $('img.image').load(function() {
  $(this).doSomething();
});

$image.doSomethingElseWithTheImage();
```