# Zurb Foundation 5 and Jquery 3 incompatible?

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, jquery-3

I am trying to use Zurb Foundation 5 with JQuery 3.0.0.1 and seem to be having some compatibility issues. When I initialize Foundation `$(document).foundation();` a javascript error is thrown

> Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf' on line 9612

If I roll back to 2.2.4 everything works fine.
Has anyone else run into this?

Browser: MS Edge(IE 11)

Comment: browser type and version?

Comment: Just check the first 20 lines.... https://wiki.bath.ac.uk/display/webservices/Foundation+5+-+Things+to+be+aware+of

Comment: That wiki article addresses Jquery 2 it doesn't address JQuery 3

Comment: with jquery migrate seems it works, but reveal...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Zurb Foundation 5 and jQuery 3 are incompatible. Foundation still uses the `load` function, which was deprecated 4 years ago in jQuery 1.8 and finally [removed in jQuery 3.0](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2286). Since there is another jQuery Function called [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which is called instead, you get this rather cryptic error message.

Even the current relased Version of Zurb Foundation 6.2.3 and jQuery 3 are incompatible. The [fix for your problem](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/pull/8923) is already merged and should be released with [version 6.2.4](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/milestone/29) which was to be released about 2 months ago, but still isn't. (Its 78% complete according to the GitHub page)

So I guess the only solution is to a) ignore the error or b) patch the code yourself as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37915907/935676).

**Update:** Foundation 6.2.4 was released October 21, 2016 and now supports jQuery 3.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this saved me a lot of headaches! The current easiest solution is downgrade jQuery to 2.2.4, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around that with a snippet like this:

```
// XXX Hack for foundation for jQuery upgrade from 2.x to 3.x
jQuery.fn.load = function (callback) {
    this.on('load', callback);
    return this;
};
```

Typescript:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';

// XXX Hack for foundation for jQuery upgrade from 2.x to 3.x
var jQueryAny = (jQuery as any).fn;
jQueryAny.load = function(cb:any) {
    this.on('load', cb);
    return this;
}
```