# Modifying the HTML content of an iframe using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have an html page that has an iframe with the src attribute pointing to another html page which already has some content in it.

parent.html

```
<body>
    <iframe src="child.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

child.html

```
<body>
    <p>test1</p>
</body>
```

parent.html also has a jquery function that tries to append a paragraph to the body of child.html:

```
$(function(){
    var $iframe = $("iframe");
    $iframe.ready(function(){
        $iframe.contents().find("body").append("<p>test2</p>");
    });

});
```

The problem is that the function is not working, the paragraph is not being added. The interesting part is that if I remove "child.html" from the src attribute of the iframe, the paragraph is being added into a blank html page.

Is it not possible to modify the content of an html document from an iframe (when the document already contains a number of elements)?

Also, there isn't any problem with the cross-domain policy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the code is executing before the iframe contents has actually loaded.  Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $iframe = $("iframe");
    $iframe.on('load', (function(){
        $iframe.contents().find("body").append("<p>test2</p>");
    });
});
```

Comment: yes, it works. I tried this before and I didn't saw that there was an error being thrown in the console "Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function". for who is interested, I used the solution from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738732/jquery-3-0-url-indexof-error      Anyway, thanks for the help, I really appreciate it

Comment: Have updated the code in my answer, thanks for the heads up :)