# add iframe for all a tags have attr target

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to add iframe for my all tags have attribute target.

I use this code.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(e) {
    jQuery('a[target]').each(function(index, element) {
       var targetLink= jQuery(this).attr('target');
       alert(targetLink);
       var newIframe=jQuery('<iframe src="" width="400" height="auto" name='+targetLink+' frameborder="0"></iframe>')
        newIframe.appendTo(jQuery('div#myMain'));
});
```

But I get error in the console

> TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function[Learn More]

How can I fix it?

Comment: which line exactly throws an error?

Comment: If you are using jQuery 3.0, `load()` has [been removed](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed). See [jquery 3.0 url.indexOf error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738732/jquery-3-0-url-indexof-error).

Answer (score 0):

i change this code to document, and its become correct.

```
jQuery(fucntion(e){
    jQuery('a[target]').each(function(index, element) {
       var targetLink= jQuery(this).attr('target');
       alert(targetLink);
       var newIframe=jQuery('<iframe src="" width="400" height="auto" name='+targetLink+' frameborder="0"></iframe>')
        newIframe.appendTo(jQuery('div#myMain'));
    });
```

i don't know why it doesn't run in window.load.