# Opening Accordion via URL -deep linking (foundation 6.4.3) not working

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation-6

i implemented the code as described in the zurb documentation. the correct ID is displayed in the URL. But as soon as I copy this URL into a new tab, the Accordion does not open.
Following JS error:

```
TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.load (jquery.js:9857)
at Accordion._checkDeepLink (foundation.js:1681)
at Accordion._init (foundation.js:1698)
at Accordion._setup (foundation.js:1619)
at Accordion.Plugin (foundation.js:164)
at new Accordion (foundation.js:1600)
at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous> (foundation.js:5490)
at Function.each (jquery.js:354)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:189)
at String.<anonymous> (foundation.js:5472)
```

part of my Accordion-Code:

```
   <ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-multi-expand="true" data-allow-all-closed="true"
                data-slide-speed="50"  data-deep-link="true" data-update-history="true" data-deep-link-smudge="true" data-deep-link-smudge-delay="500" id="deeplinked-accordion">
                <li class="accordion-item first" data-accordion-item>
                    <a href="#anwendungsgebite" class="accordion-title zu">Anwendungsgebiet<span class="open"></span></a>
                    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content style="position: relative">
                        <p>Benocten hilft Ihnen bei kurzfristigen Ein- und Durchschlafstörungen durch:</p>
                        <ul>
                            <li>nervöse Unruhe</li>
                            <li>Stress</li>
                            <li>Umstellungen auf Reisen</li>
                            <li>nächtlichem Husten (ausser Asthma)</li>
                            <li>Erkältung</li>
                            <li>Juckreiz</li>
                            <li>allergische Begleitsymptome</li>
                        </ul>
                       <div class="close_accordion"></div>

                    </div>
                </li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery 3.0 url.indexOf error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738732/jquery-3-0-url-indexof-error)

Comment: The issue seems to be have been fixed in 6.4.3 
https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/10913

Comment: i've updates the js via cdn to 6.5.0. The TypeError is gone. But the deep linking still not work.

Comment: That needs to be a separate question with code snippets. If possible a working snippet with the issue.