# Select Closest href Match With jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

trying to narrow down `<a>` `hrefs` to one with `jQuery` filter and then add the tag `active` class. 
I am doing this because I get redirected from sidebar submenu and want to still keep sidebar menu open.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var url = window.location;


  $('ul.treeview-menu a').filter(function () {
      return url.indexOf(this.href) > -1;
  }).parentsUntil(".sidebar-menu > .treeview-menu").addClass('active');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
    <li class="header">General</li>
    <li class="home"><a href="/p/index.php"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> <span> Dashboard</span></a></li>

    <li class="header">Data Managment</li>
    <li class="treeview">
        <a href="#">p <span>Tree</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="/p/pages/foo.php">foo</a></li>
            <li><a href="/p/pages/bar.php">bar</a></li>
            <li><a href="/p/pages/blah.php">blah</a></li>
            <li><a href="/p/pages/blahh.php">blahh</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li class="treeview">
        <a href="#"></i> <span>Tree 2</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="/p/pages/aaa.php">aaa</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

then if I get redirected inside `foo` and `href` be like `/p/pages/foo.php/new.php` I still want to foo be active.

why don't this work?

Comment: without looking too closely (and without relevant html), this bit `.parentsUntil(".sidebar-menu > .treeview-menu").addClass('active')` *looks like* it should be `.closest(".sidebar-menu").find(".treeview-menu").addClass('active')`

Comment: @freedomn-m unfortunately didn't work. i'll try to share some html

Comment: You should compare `window.location` with `this.href` (by "compare" I mean console.log them and see what you're actually getting.  It's hard to tell if the issue is the .filter or the .closest.   Also "didn't work" and "why doesn't this work" don't really help - do they do *something*? *anything*?  How many results do you get from your `.filter`?

Comment: Assuming your .filter gives one result, from your html, your parentsUntil / find should highlight all of the .treeview-menu's - again, assuming your .filter works... it would be `.filter(..).closest(".treeview-menu").addClass("active")`

Comment: @freedomn-m i get this error in console `url.indexOf is not a function` and `.closest(".sidebar-menu").find(".treeview-menu").addClass('active')` returns all of them but html is not right

Comment: @freedomn-m console error is gone by replacing `url` with `window.location.href`

Comment: @freedomn-m `return console.log(window.location.href.indexOf(this.href) > -1)` returns `false`. it means it can't find anything!?

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(window.location.href, this.href)` on each of the `a` (inside the .filter)?

Comment: @freedomn-m nothing. it's empty

Comment: Your window.location.href is empty?  Not going to be able to match on it then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way would be using `each` loop and then comparing if the `url  == this.href` if yes then add class to that li and open closest `ul`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //just for demo...
  var url = 'https://stacksnippets.net/p/pages/bar.php';
  $('ul.treeview-menu a').each(function() {
    //if full url is not same with li use indexof else if http://...also there in href of a tag use below..
    if (url == this.href) {
      $(this).addClass('active') //add class active to `a`
      $(this).closest("ul").slideDown(); //slide ul tag where `li` is active
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.treeview-menu {
  display: none
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
  <li class="header">General</li>
  <li class="home"><a href="/p/index.php"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> <span> Dashboard</span></a></li>

  <li class="header">Data Managment</li>
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="#">p <span>Tree</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li><a href="https://stacksnippets.net/p/pages/foo.php">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://stacksnippets.net/p/pages/bar.php">bar</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://stacksnippets.net/p/pages/blah.php">blah</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://stacksnippets.net/p/pages/blahh.php">blahh</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="#"> <span>Tree 2</span>
      <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li><a href="https://stacksnippets.net/p/pages/aaa.php">aaa</a></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

*Updated Code* :

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var new_url = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  $('ul.treeview-menu a').each(function() {
    var res = this.href.replace(".php", "");
    var href = res + "/" + new_url;
    if (href == url) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('active') //add class active to `a
      $(this).closest("ul").slideDown(); //slide ul tag where `li` is active
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: the urls are not the same and i have been redirected from submenu, and the new url has a new part at the end now how would you use `indexOf`?

Comment: Hi like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/935d4rs7/) check if that works for you .

Comment: Hi :) i can't tell, i couldn't get rid of this error `jQuery.Deferred exception: url.lastIndexOf is not a function TypeError: url.lastIndexOf is not a function` and `Uncaught TypeError: url.lastIndexOf is not a function` sorry for my beginner questions

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738732/jquery-3-0-url-indexof-error) post try that suggestion see if that works or not :)

Comment: ok i did kind of solve the error. and `console.log(new_url)` shows urls last part like this `new.php` and if statement returns empty

Comment: rn the `new_url` returning `new.php` and each loop and `this.href` is showing the sidebar urls + returning new url multiple time with a number at the left side witch is the length of each treeview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228415/discussion-between-swati-and-ramiel).